# Can't put a delegate method to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I;m using Ajax in a bootstrap PHP page, so i can't use functions inside `onsubmit` event, since the button didn't exist before, and so, i have to use delegate methods, i understand this.

But, as i don't know what i am doing wrong, im here to ask your help.
I have a `<input><button>` inside a table, which i feed via Ajax, and i want to validate it's data before submiting, i thought of using a delegate method to do that, the validation is very simple, just don't be empty.

my code is...

```
<label for="idmat" class="label label-default">mat:</label>
<input placeholder="mat" type="text" class="mat" id="idmat"    name="sendmat" size="20" maxlenght="20" /><br />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit" class="btmat" id="btmat">Mat</button>
```

and my JS is:

```
$(function(){
$("#btmat").delegate("click",function(){
var matric = $("#idmat").val();
if(matric === ""){
    alert("wrong!");
}
});
...etc
```

I tried changing this `.delegate` to `.on`, but it didn't do anything different than before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to the DOM element, and listen for the creation:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#btmat', function() {
    var matric = $("#idmat").val();
    if(matric === ""){
        alert("wrong!");
    }
});
```

Also, your button can't set `class` twice. You need to change it to this:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success btmat" type="submit" id="btmat">Mat</button>
```

Comment: @IgorJasbinschek Sweet, you can read more about [`jQuery().on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to find out how it actually works :)

Comment: I will, i thought it should target the ID itself, didn't notice that it had to target the page, most examples i saw on internet target a tag or a class...
Thanks again.

Comment: Simple to remember, if it's already in the html when you load the site, you target the id/class, otherwise if you load/create it dynamically, you target the `document` :)